# Dual booting two instances of Windows 10, how to encrypt one so the other cannot access?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, encryption, dualboot, veracrypt

I currently have two separate instances of Windows 10 Home installed on two different SSD's in my machine. I want to encrypt one instance (my main install) and the associated files which are on several other SSD's/HDD's, as I don't want these viewable from the second install. I don't need/want to encrypt the second install which will be used for testing and won't have personal info saved down. When I restart my computer I currently am greeted with a blue Windows screen and asked to select which install I would like to boot into. Ideally, I would like to keep this process and only have to enter my encryption password when I select my main install. Bonus points would be if I can enter a single password to access my main install and the encrypted drives with my files (i.e., not having to unlock the other drives separately). Currently, BIOS is set to Legacy + UEFI and I do have TPM 2.0 available.

Is this possible to do with Veracrypt? Or will I have to upgrade to Windows Pro and use Bitlocker?

I've looked but only really seen people trying to dual boot Windows and Linux. I really need the two installs of Windows...

[image: Windows boot screen I see currently]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to setup the test environment in a
virtual machine.

This way the VM will be uncoupled from your main system, which can still
be partially visible to the VM by a mechanism such as shared folders.

Take a backup of the VM, and replace the running version if it goes bad.